# Firestore - proper NoSQL structure for user-specific data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app with Firestore. I use Firebase Authentication for managing users.
The thing is that most of the data in my app would be user-specific. Meaning that users should only have access to their own data.

I've already done research about Firestore security rules, so I know how to handle the security part.

However, I'm wondering how to properly model user-specific data in general. First piece of data I'm adding are `categories`, that have (for now) 2 properties: `name` and `type`.

After some research, I found it's good to create a collection called `categories` and then a document per-user, each named after the user's ID (UID).

But then, within such a user-specific document, I want to add my categories. One way I figured it out is like on the screenshot below:

[image: firestore data model - document per user in categories collection, then maps with name and type for each category]

So, to describe this approach in a more generic way:

1. New collection for each data type (e.g. `categories`)
2. Inside the collection, separate document named with UID for each user
3. In each user-specific document, a map with an object's data (e.g. `category_1` map with fields `name = groceries` and `type = expense`

However, what worries me here is that I need to somehow invent these names of the maps like `category_1`, `category_2` etc... I have a feeling something is wrong in this model, but my strong SQL background doesn't allow me to think that through

Do you have any ideas whether this model is a good one or what problems could it produce later? Maybe you can suggest a better approach for modeling user-specific data in Firestore database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any limit on how many categories can a single user have? If not then it'll be better to create a collection for categories to avoid hitting [1 MB max document size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). If there is a limit and you decide to use a map, I'd recommend creating a map field `categories` and them as it's children as shown below so if you add any other fields in the document, it'll be much more *categorized*:

```
{
  categories: {
    category_1: {
      name: "",
      type: ""
    },
    category_2: {
      name: "",
      type: ""
    }
  }
}
```

However, creating a sub-collection could be better choice as well if each category gets more data in future and you need some queries on categories.

```
users -> {userId} -> categories -> {categoryId}
(col)     (doc)        (col)          (doc)
```

As the categories are in a sub-collection you don't need to add userId field in every category document. However you can also create 2 different root collections namely - users and categories:

```
users -> {userId}
(col)      (doc)

categories -> {categoryId}
(col)           (doc)
```

In this case you would have to store `userId` field to filter between owner of those categories.

[@Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) has perfectly explained difference between using a root level collection and a sub-collection in this post if you need an in-depth explanation: [What are the benefits of using a root collection in Firestore vs. a subcollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662007/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-root-collection-in-firestore-vs-a-subcollectio/68727499#68727499)

---

Security rules will be different in both the cases. If you use sub-collections then you can just read user UID from the wildcard like this:

```
match /users/{userId}/categories/{categoryId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

However, if you use a root level collection, the document ID for each category usually won't have user's UID but the UID will be stored in the document as a field. In that case you would have to read the `userId` from the document being requested.

```
match /categories/{categoryId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
}
```

---

> what worries me here is that I need to somehow invent these names of the maps

NoSQL database don't have a schema. You can dynamically add any key as required. Just treat every document as a JSON object.

```js
const newKey = "category_123"
const newValue = {name: "newCatName", type: "expense"}

const userDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("userId")
userDoc.update({
  [`categories.${newKey}`]: newValue
})
```

This update operation will create a new child in 'categories' map with the provided values.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It cleared my mind about what was worrying me :) I think I'll go with `users` top collection and `categories` subcollection, i.e. users -> {userId} -> categories -> {categoryId}. Categories are not global/shared between users in my app, they will always be processed within a user context. I think this would make querying and security easier.