# FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. serverTimestamp() is not currently supported inside arrays

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update the document with the new `comments` array but I'm getting this error when I submit a new comment. In every document, there is an array(comments array) of object(single comment)

```
FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. serverTimestamp() is not currently supported inside arrays (found in document solutions/wLflWVhLueEKjBBknHNi)
```

comment submit code:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const commentToAdd = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        content: newComment.trim(),
        reactions: [],
        user: {
          userID: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        },
        replies: [],
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      }
      await updateDocument(id, {
        comments: [...solution.comments, commentToAdd],
      })
      setNewComment("")
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

updateDocument hook code:

```
  const updateDocument = async (id, updates) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(updates))
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })
    try {
      const updatedDocument = await updateDoc(doc(db, c, id), updates)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "UPDATED_DOCUMENT", payload: updatedDocument })
      return updatedDocument
    } catch (error) {
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error })
      return null
    }
  }
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Comment: As the error says, you cannot use `serverTimestamp()` in side an array. You can store comments in a sub-collection instead of an array that'll also prevent you from reaching 1 MB max size of document if there are many comments.

Comment: So, I need to add comments sub-collection to every document that I have in the solutions collection.

Comment: Yes, that's one way you could do. I am not sure about you DB structure but let's say it's a posts collection and you have comments on it, then you could do `posts -> postId -> comments -> commentId` where every comment would be a document on it's own

Comment: Can you please suggest some resources to learn about sub-collections? I have never used sub-collections before.

Comment: Yes, checkout Firestore's [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections), [this video by Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s) and [Firestore - proper NoSQL structure for user-specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68827421/13130697) as an example. If you could share your use case then there might be some similar posts.

Comment: This is my website: https://www.codingspace.codes/. I'm trying to add a comments section on the solution details page(https://www.codingspace.codes/solution/wLflWVhLueEKjBBknHNi), so users can comment on each solution. I have a solutions collection and in the solutions collection, I have a document for each solution that contains all the information related to the solution including comments associated with each solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
createdAt: serverTimestamp()
```

Use this:

```
createdAt: Timestamp.now()
```

You can find more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)