# Which is best, sub collection or root collection to work with Algolia search in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to ask which is best for this case to implement in Firestore?

For instance, I have a list of transactions.
In this list, I want to:

1. Query and Sort.
2. Full-text search using Algolia.
3. Apply rules.

Should I use root collection which contains all transactions from all users, or create a sub-collection named transactions in each user?

A solution I look at should be efficient at cost and performance.

I have read:

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

But no mention for Algolia.
I also have read Algolia docs, but there is no tutorial on how to implement Algolia search on sub-collection using the firebase extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to index documents in a sub-collection you can use a wildcard as shown below:

```
users/{userId}/transactions
```

It's mentioned in the extension's Github home page [here](https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search#:%7E:text=For%20subcollection%2C%20the%20syntax).

---

About root level collection vs sub-collections, you can check this answer by @Alex:

[What are the benefits of using a root collection in Firestore vs. a subcollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662007/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-root-collection-in-firestore-vs-a-subcollectio)