# Does 1 mb size limit apply to a sub collection in inside a document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I create a sub collection in certain document would this sub collection and its nested documents have the size limit of the parent document of that sub-collection? Or once a sub-collection gets created a new limit for its documents is available? In other words does firestore regard a sub collection as a part of a parent document regarding size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a sub-collection under a document, that sub-collection doesn't count towards the 1 MiB limitation of the document. Besides that, all documents within that sub-collection have their own 1 MiB maximum limitation.

Comment: Is there any thing to know regarding nesting this way ? Performance wise ?

Comment: No, [Firestore is as fast as it is at level 1 is also at level 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662007/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-root-collection-in-firestore-vs-a-subcollectio). So no worries.