# Firestore social media friend requests data model

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I am using Firestore to build a social media app, I am wondering what is the best way to structure the data for friend requests is.

When a user John wants to friend request Mary and Anne, Do I create a root collection called `friend_requests` and add 3 documents:

1. A document with John’s `userId` as a key the value of which will be an object each for both Mary and Anne’s containing their `userId` and the `status` of request (pending/accepted/declined)
2. A document with Mary’s `userId` as a key and an array with an object with John's `userId` and `status` of request
3. A document with Annes’s `userId` as a key and an array with an object with John's `userId` and `status` of request

Now, when Anne and Mary accept the friend request, I delete all three documents in `friend_requests` collection and then:

- I add a subcollection for each user (in `users` root collection) called `friends` that contains usersIds, displayNames, and photoURLs of friends that have accepted requests

or

- Should I make another root collection `friends` that has a document for each user containing the friends information instead?

It seems like a lot of duplicate data so I'm trying to wrap my head around it and find the best and most efficient way to do it in Firestore. Any advice would be much appreciated and maybe I am going about it the wrong way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Dharmaraj's solution will certainly work, I think that there is an even simpler solution for that, that can help you reduce the number of reads a little bit. So let's assume `userOne` sends a friend request to `userTwo`, and `userThree` sends a friend request to the `userOne`.

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
  |    |
  |    --- $userOneUid (document)
  |    |     |
  |    |     --- //User data
  |    |
  |    --- $userTwoUid (document)
  |    |     |
  |    |     --- //User data
  |    |
  |    --- $userThreeUid (document)
  |          |
  |          --- //User data
  |
  --- requests (collection)
       |
       --- $userOneUid (document)
       |     |
       |     --- ownRequests (map)
       |     |      |
       |     |      --- $userTwoUid
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- displayName: "User Two"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- status: "requested"
       |     |
       |     --- friendRequests (map)
       |     |      |
       |     |      --- $userThreeUid
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- displayName: "User Three"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- status: "requested"
       |     |
       |     --- allFriends (map)
       |            |
       |            --- //All friends
       |
       --- $userTwoUid (document)
       |     |
       |     --- friendRequests (map)
       |            |
       |            --- $userOneUid
       |                   |
       |                   --- displayName: "User One"
       |                   |
       |                   --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |                   |
       |                   --- status: "requested"
       |
       --- $userThreeUid (document)
             |
             --- ownRequests (map)
                    |
                    --- $userOneUid
                           |
                           --- displayName: "User One"
                           |
                           --- photoUrl: "https://"
                           |
                           --- status: "requested"
```

To have a flattened schema, instead of creating nested collections or nested maps under the User object, I have created a separate top-level collection called `requests`. Inside this collection, there will be documents that will manage the user's own requests, friend requests, and all friends.

Seeing this schema, you might think, oh, but how can I manage to add such an amount of data in a single document? Even if we're limited to storing up to [1 Mib of storage in a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), when it comes to storing such simple objects, we can store pretty much. However, if you're worried about the space, then you should consider creating separate collections for each situation, `ownRequests`, `friendRequests`, and `allFriends`. In this case, for simplicity, let's assume all the data fits into a single document.

Going forward, as you can see, we have stored the minimum data from a User object under each map, where the key is the UID and the value is represented by three fields. In this way you can display the name and the profile photo, to clearly indicate the user who performed the friend request.

Now, when `userOne` sends a friend request to `userTwo`, there are two operations that need to be done. The first one would be to add `userOne` inside the `friendRequests` map of `userTwo` and the second one would be to add `userTwo` under its own `ownRequests` map.

Between these two friends we have now a friend request, this means that you'll always have to make sure that you'll restrict `userTwo` from sending friend requests to `userOne`. How can you do that? Simply by checking the existence of the `$userTwoUid` inside `ownRequests` of `userOne`. If you want the `userOne` to be able to cancel the friend request, or `userTwo` to reject the friend request, then simply revert the above two operations.

The same rule applies in the case `userThree`.

Regarding displaying data, if you want to show a list of your own requests, friend requests, or a list of all friends, you need to make a **single** database call, that costs a **single** read. If you however need to load more data of a user, then when you click on the user, you can perform another request and load all the data of the user, since you already know the UID.

When `userTwo` accepts the friend request from `userOne`, simply move their objects inside `allFriends` map. You can also go ahead and add a `bannerFriends` if you want, to prevent some other users from sending friend requests. Please also note, that this will also cost only a **single** read.

> It seems like a lot of duplicate data so I'm trying to wrap my head around it and find the best and most efficient way to do it in Firestore.

Denormalizing data it's a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases like Firestore and for that I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [What is denormalization in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore/)

Where you'll also be able to see other solutions for structuring such a database.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Much appreciated

Comment: That's pretty cool answer, I've planned similar structure for my app where I also need friends & friend requests functionality. My question is, how are you handling delete user operation having this collections structure?
I assume you need to delete user and then delete friends document. But you also need to find any requests from and to ur user which were created and documents where user you want to delete is listed. So that at the end of the day is a lot of write operations. Of course it can be achieved in easy and straightforward way as every uid you need is already in ur user friends doc.

Comment: @szibi At the end of the day there are a lot of write operations but compared to the number of reads, those deletes are incredibly fewer. So most likely it worth it.

Comment: how would we setup security rules for this?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach seems to have a lot of document creations and deletions. Instead you could create a sub-collection "friends" under "users" and store a field "status". So the structure would be:

```
users -> {userId} -> friends -> {friendId}
```

When User2 sends a friend request to User1, you can add a friend sub-document under User1 and set the `status` field to `requested` along with `friendId`. Once User1 accepts the request, just update the status to `active`. This will reduce costs of that 1 delete and 1 create operations per friend request.

This should cover many use cases including:

1. Listing friends/friend request of a users
2. Listing pending friend requests sent by me (a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) can be used if you use sub-collection)

You can use [Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) if you need to process anything like updating database, sending a notification/e-mail, etc when the friend request has been accepted.

---

The `friends` sub-collection could be a root-level collection but in that case you'll have to add another field `userId` to filter of friends of a given user. That doesn't make a big difference but checkout [What are the benefits of using a root collection in Firestore vs. a subcollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662007/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-root-collection-in-firestore-vs-a-subcollectio) for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks but if user2 sends request to user1 and I add to user1's friends collection, how will user2 then know when user1 has accepted. Would I not have to have a document in user2's friend collection as well so that they know they are connected/pending a request for user1?

Comment: @user3214545 right, you can use [Firestore triggers for Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and listen for any updates on the friend document. Once User1 accepts it, you'll update the status that'll trigger this function and you can process anything in it e.g. add a friend doc on User2' s end, sending  an email or notification using FCM, etc.