How to delete a key:value pair from Firebase map?
I have some code for managing a friend system using Firebase. The issue I am having is when a user accepts a friend request the request can be deleted. So this involves adding user1 to user2's friends and user2 to user1's friends then removing user2 from user1's 'ownRequests' and removing user1 from user2's 'friendRequests'. I am trying to use Firestore's DELETE_FIELD but it does not appear to work.
The schema is:
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
  |    |
  |    --- $userOneUid (document)
  |    |     |
  |    |     --- //User data
  |    |
  |    --- $userTwoUid (document)
  |    |     |
  |    |     --- //User data
  |    |
  |    --- $userThreeUid (document)
  |          |
  |          --- //User data
  |
  --- requests (collection)
       |
       --- $userOneUid (document)
       |     |
       |     --- ownRequests (map)
       |     |      |
       |     |      --- $userTwoUid
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- displayName: "User Two"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- status: "requested"
       |     |
       |     --- friendRequests (map)
       |     |      |
       |     |      --- $userThreeUid
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- displayName: "User Three"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |     |             |
       |     |             --- status: "requested"
       |     |
       |     --- allFriends (map)
       |            |
       |            --- //All friends
       |
       --- $userTwoUid (document)
       |     |
       |     --- friendRequests (map)
       |            |
       |            --- $userOneUid
       |                   |
       |                   --- displayName: "User One"
       |                   |
       |                   --- photoUrl: "https://"
       |                   |
       |                   --- status: "requested"
       |
       --- $userThreeUid (document)
             |
             --- ownRequests (map)
                    |
                    --- $userOneUid
                           |
                           --- displayName: "User One"
                           |
                           --- photoUrl: "https://"
                           |
                           --- status: "requested"


# accept/reject friend request
@router.post("/accept_friend_request")
def accept_friend_request(friend_req: FriendRequest): # pass req uid and accept uid
    requester_ref = db.collection('Requests').document(friend_req.requester)
    recipient_ref = db.collection('Requests').document(friend_req.recipient)
    transaction = db.transaction()
    try:
        transaction = db.transaction()
        accept_friend_request_transaction(transaction, requester_ref, recipient_ref, friend_req)
        transaction.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))

@firestore.transactional
def accept_friend_request_transaction(transaction: Transaction, requester_ref, recipient_ref, friend_req: FriendRequest):
    requester_doc = requester_ref.get(transaction=transaction)
    recipient_doc = recipient_ref.get(transaction=transaction)

    if requester_doc.exists and recipient_doc.exists:
        transaction.update(recipient_ref, {
            f'allFriends.{friend_req.requester}': 'true' 
        })
        transaction.update(requester_ref, {
            f'allFriends.{friend_req.recipient}': 'true'
        })
        transaction.update(requester_ref, {
            f'ownRequests.{friend_req.recipient}': firestore.DELETE_FIELD 
        })
        transaction.update(recipient_ref, {
            f'friendRequests.{friend_req.requester}': firestore.DELETE_FIELD
        })

The updating of the appropriate friends lists works but deleting the requests from the respective maps does not delete them. I tried using firestore.DELETE_FIELD but that does not appear to work correctly and I am not sure why.

"it does not appear to work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

@AlexMamo when I test this endpoint the update to both of the allFriends maps works as expected however the call to DELETE_FIELD to remove the request from the appropriate maps does not delete the field. I am thinking this is because this is not deleting a field but rather a key:val pair in a map field. Basically is it possible to just delete the key and associated value without pulling the whole map, deleting the key then rewriting the new map to the database. Does that clarify my issue?

Yes, it's possible. What is the exact key-value pair that exists inside the map that you want to delete?

@AlexMamo
They are created like so:
requester_ref = db.collection('Requests').document(friend_req.requester)
recipient_ref = db.collection('Requests').document(friend_req.recipient)
transaction.update(requester_ref, {
f'ownRequests.{friend_req.recipient}': 'pending'
})
So I would want to delete the entry of ownRequests.uid
ownRequests
(map)
y7Nbrga0oZMwygIauXLqTNnBMSu1 : "pending"

I was asking what is the exact key-value pair that exists inside the map in the your document, which you want to be deleted.

@AlexMamo
XaTxXAy5V4ehQgb9wlKwif1vYn72 (key) :  (value-map) {status: "accepted"}
Per the solution you presented in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706094/firestore-social-media-friend-requests-data-model

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database.

@AlexMamo edited question to include screenshot of firebase.

Thanks for providing the screenshot. I'll write you an answer right away.

If you want to delete the key-value pair status: "accepted" that exists inside the nested Map in the Firestore document, then you have to create a reference that points to that document:
doc_ref = db.collection('Requests').document('2Bxq...RFv2')

Localize the key-value pair inside the document and call update like below:
doc_ref.update({'allFriends.XaTx...Yn72.status': firestore.DELETE_FIELD})
//                                  

The key to solving this problem is to use the . (dot) to dig inside the Map field.

I see, and what if I wanted to delete the parent of that i.e. ownRequests.XaTx.... which would make the ownRequests empty in the provided screenshot in the question.

If you want to remove the entire XaTx...Yn72 key, then you have to use doc_ref.update({'allFriends.XaTx...Yn72': firestore.DELETE_FIELD}). See there is no .status anymore?

So did my answer solve your problem? Can I help you with other information?

Yes, thank you so much for your help.
