# How to organize FireStore Collections and Documents based on app similar to BlaBlaCar rides

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

It's my first time working with FireStore. I'm working on a ridesharing app with Flutter that uses Firebase Auth where users can create trips and offer rides similarly to BlaBlaCar, where other users can send requests to join a ride. I’m having difficulty not only deciding the potential collections and paths to use, but also how to even structure it.

For simplicity at this stage, I want any user to be able to see all trips created, but when they go to their “My Rides” page, they will only see the rides that they’ve participated in. I would be grateful for any kind of feedback.

Here are the options I’ve considered:

1. Two collections, “Users” and “Trips”. The path would look something like this:
   users/uid and trips/tripsId with a created_by field
   [image: two collections]
2. One collection of “Users” and a sub-collection of “Trips". The path seems to make more sense to me, which would be users/uid/trips/tripId but then I don't know how other users could access all the rides on their home feed.
   [image]

I'm inclined to go with the first option of two collections. Also very open to any other suggestions or help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68662007/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-root-collection-in-firestore-vs-a-subcollectio) will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want any user to be able to see all trips created, but when they go
> to their “My Rides” page, they will only see the rides that they’ve
> participated in

I make the assumption that participating in a ride is either being the author or being a passenger of the ride.

I would go for 2 collections: one for `users` and one for `trips`. In a trip document you add two fields:

- `createdBy` with the uid of the creator
- `participants`: an Array where you store the author's uid and all the other participants uids (passengers)

This way you can easily query for:

- All the rides
- All the rides created by a user
- All the rides for which a user is a participant, using [`arrayContains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_6).

*(Regarding the limit of 1 MiB for the maximum size for a document I guess this is not a problem because the number of passengers of a ride shouldn't be so huge that the Array fields size makes the document larger than 1 Mib!)*

---

Note that the second approach with subcollections could also be used since you can query with [collections group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) but, based on the elements in your question, I don't see any technical advantage.